# Saving in Laravel when retrieving multiple records

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i'm trying to save or update, when retrivieng mutliple records, but can't get it work..

**When doing this, at first it look like it worked:**

```
$c = Customer::select('Name', 'City');
$c[0]->update(array('Name' =>  'new Name'));
var_dump($c[0]['Name']);
```

**But after a refresh and test it like that, i still see the oldname:**

```
$c = Customer::select('Name', 'City');
var_dump($c[0]['Name']);
```

Somebody knows what i'm doing wrog?

i Have retrieve a json thing:

```
 data[0][Name]:Afrifield Corporation
 data[0][City]:Maidstone
 data[1][Name]:Amann Informatik AG
 data[1][City]:Reinach BL
 data[2][Name]:Antarcticopy
 data[2][City]:Antwerpen
```

if also have the columns Name and City which i want to update with this retrieved array..

**so last question there is no faster solution than:**

```
    $custNo = Customer::select('Name', 'No_')->get();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($custNo); $i++) {
        $c = Customer::select('Name', 'City')->where('No_','=',$custNo[$i]->No_);
        $c->update(array('Name' =>  $input['data'][$i]['Name']));
    }
```

No_ is my PrimaryKey i also set this in the model class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `get()` and `$c[0]`, try using `first()`. You also need to re-fetch after updating. And it's object, not an array. So `$c['Name']` won't work unless you alter it to an array.

```
$customers = Customer::select('Name', 'City')->where('No_','=','DKT000142')->get();
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $customer->update(array('Name' =>  'new Name'));
    //you need to re-fetch for the updated data, assuming you have an id field
    $currentCustomer = Customer::find($customer->id);
    echo var_dump($currentCustomer->Name);
}
```

Edit: Also for mass updating, you can try something like:

```
$update = Customer::where('No_','=','DKT000142')->update(array('Name' =>  'new Name'));
```

Edit2: To both get mass update and get updated records, this is the best approach I can think of:

```
//First, we mass-update
$update = Customer::where('No_','=','DKT000142')->update(array('Name' =>  'new Name'));

//Then we get the updated data and loop:
$customers = Customer::select('Name', 'City')->where('No_','=','DKT000142')->get();
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    echo var_dump($currentCustomer->Name);
}
```

Comment: but like this i only retrieve the first record, and i would like to retrieve multiple records.. see updated question

Comment: @user2834172 Updated my answer for loop situations. I've assumed you have an `id` field primary key for the customers table.

Comment: updated question if u want to clarify last part for me? but it works now, but i think there should be a better way to do this...

Comment: @user2834172 by the last part, did you mean my answer's last part or your question's?

Comment: question -> is there no faster way then looping..?

Comment: @user2834172 Assuming you want to mass update and get individual updated records, I've added a "Edit2" section in my answer. Laravel methods return a collection, so to get "each" record individually, you need to loop either with `foreach` or `for`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$c[0]->name = "New name";
$c[0]->save();
```